# Tap Gesture Recognizer too slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

I am having difficulty getting a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect every tap that is occurring. For context, I am making a drumming app. I have gotten the tap gesture recognizer to work correctly, but the user should be able to tap very quickly to drum, and the recognizer is only picking up on let's say a tap every so often (if you try to tap as quickly as you can).

I am guessing this has to do with iOS categorizing very quick taps in a row as one gesture, but is there any way to get every time a finger goes down as a tap event?

I have tried using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` with a small press duration.

I have tried setting the `requiredNumberofTouches` and `requiredNumberofTaps` to 1.

The code does not seem necessary to post in order to answer the question, but I will post it if you request it.

Any help would be most appreciated!

EDIT: I am adding my code, since it may help:

```
-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {

    CGPoint location = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:[self view]];

    switch ([self validateTouchLocation:location]) {
        case 0:
            return;
        case 1:
            [[ASSoundManager sharedManager] playSoundNamed:@"SD0025" ofType:@"mp3"];
            break;
        case 2:
        default:
            [[ASSoundManager sharedManager] playSoundNamed:@"SD0010" ofType:@"mp3"];
            break;
    }

    float tapWidth = 30;
    ASDrumTapView *drumTapView = [[ASDrumTapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x - (tapWidth / 2), location.y - (tapWidth / 2), tapWidth, tapWidth)];
    [drumTapView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [drumTapView setNeedsDisplay];
    [[self view] addSubview:drumTapView];

    float animDuration = 0.75;
    CGRect frame = [drumTapView frame];

    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:animDuration
                                   delay:0.0
                                 options:0
                              animations:^{
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0
                                                          relativeDuration:animDuration
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    [drumTapView setFrame:CGRectInset(frame, -frame.size.width, -frame.size.height)];
                                                                }];
                                  [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0
                                                          relativeDuration:3*animDuration/5
                                                                animations:^{
                                                                    [[drumTapView layer] setOpacity:0.0];
                                                                }];
                              }
                              completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                  [drumTapView removeFromSuperview];
                              }];
}
```

Comment: Do you try with `uitapgesturerecognizer` ?

Comment: Yes (as I stated in the first paragraph). I have tried `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed it. Did you try with touches event: `touchesBegan` ...?

Comment: Yep. Same functionality. It works for taps in general, but if you try to tap really quickly in a row, it won't pick up on every tap.

Comment: What did you do inside the gesture recognizer selector, looks like some time consuming stuff blocked the main thread

Comment: Interesting thought. I am playing a system sound (since it is a drumming app). I am also adding a new view and animating it for `0.75` seconds, although I know for fact the animation is returning asynchronously. Could I put it on another thread? I thought UI stuff had to run on the main thread?

Answer (score 3):

There could be many reason:

- One possible reason could be fact that your audio engine cannot play next sound before previous sound has finished.
- Check `multipleTouchEnabled` property on `UIView`
- If your view is embedded in `UIScrollView` or any derived class, check `delaysContentTouches` property

Comment: I appreciate your input. I have now enabled `multipleTouchEnabled`. I have also checked `delaysContentTouches` but that is not applicable in this case. Also, I am using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` which returns asynchronously, so it should be able to play another sound even if the previous one has not finished.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: @AdamSuskin there is definitely too many things happens in your `tap:` methods. IMHO this is performance issue. Allocations are slow, also `[[ASSoundManager sharedManager] playSoundNamed:@"SD0025" ofType:@"mp3"];` looks like loading resources, which is even slower. I've also developed drumming app which is currently available in AppStore. Make audio things works fast requires lots of code optimization.

Comment: It seems you are right. After commenting out the animation code, it picks up on taps quite well. If you edit your answer just to include performance issues, I will accept it.

Also my `ASSoundManager` loads all the possible sounds before I call play so thats not a problem.

Just out of curiosity, is there any way to keep the animation code and run it in the background? I really want those animations to occur, but obviously not if it interrupts tap detection as badly as it does.

Answer (score 1):

While I appreciate everyone's input, I figured it out on my own.

In my code, I am running a keyframe animation with options set to `0`. What this means is that during the animation, user interaction with the view is not enabled.

By setting `options` to `UIKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`, I am able to pick up on taps even though one of the subviews is still in animation.

Hope this helps someone else!